# PHP Access Denied

Tags: php, mysql, connection

When I try to connect to my database from PHP I get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'XXX'@'%' to database 'XXX'
```

I am using this code to connect:

```
$con = mysql_connect('XXX.db.XXX.hostedresource.com', 'XXX', 'XXX') or die (mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("DB", $con);
```

Comment: Access denied. Consult your hoster's admin panel regarding access grants and valid credentials.

Comment: I have checked my username, password and hostname 15 times now. Is there anything else that could go wrong?

Comment: Only one thing: access isn't granted to this username to use this database.

Comment: If your db & your source hosted @same place than try giving hostname as `localhost`..

Comment: DON'T USE MYSQL-CONNECT use PDO. Please do us all a favor.

Comment: Can you connect on the command line with those credentials?

Comment: @RikeshShah GoDaddy setup their servers so I can't use localhost. Very annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally means username/password is not correct.Be sure that hostname from you are trying to connect actually can connect it.This has nothing to do with PHP itself.
If you have root privilege you can check following command:

```
show grants
```

Comment: That proves my username is correct and for the password, I copied and pasted it and it still gave me that error. Actually it gave me this: `Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES) in /home/content/xx/xxx/xxxx/xxxx/.conf.php on line 7
Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)` That error got longer and more complex...

Comment: That proves that username and password used as parameters to mysql_connect are not correct, or you don't have access to cennect due to ACL.I would like to propose to open any GUI tool (HeidiSQL,SQLDeveloper,....) and put credentials there.All tools will said that access is denied.You can not connect using this credentials from your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have assigned your user to this database ? Also check its permissions.

Comment: Yes it is, it is actually the admin account.